# How to get UWP control's source code?

Tags: wpf, uwp, code-completion

I want to learn the solution in UWP to fix bug in wpf that I used the DotPeek to decompilate the UWP ListView control but I got the result without source code.

How to get the uwp control's source code?

I use some tool software to decompilate the control of uwp but I cant get the source code.

What I want is I can get the source code that can run in VisualStudio or you can support me a site like https://referencesource.microsoft.com/ that can see some source code.

As we know, WPF cant do some thing well but UWP can that I want to learn it.

Comment: It is maybe easier to ask - how to fix your specific bug - then going the long way mate.

Comment: @Peter I will edit it

Comment: Actually, UWP can't do what WPF can do *yet*. You don't learn it because it has more capabilities though. You should learn it because it's used in Store applications, and WPF can't. If a customer wants a *desktop* application though, you'd have to use WPF

Comment: @lindexi as for the source - why do you think you need it? What is your problem? *Are* you using MVVM? *Are* you using data binding, templating? The you shouldn't even care what the container is - ListView, StackPanel, WrapPanel. They all work in similar ways, to the point that you can bind *any* list to *any* `ItemsContainer` control

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thx, but I can see some thing I can write in wpf.

Comment: @lindexi that comment doesn't explain anything. Do you have a *specific* question?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I found some bug in wpf in https://github.com/iip-easi/wpf-issues

Comment: @lindexi just by looking at `#4` it looks like you found bugs *in your code*, not WPF. **NO BACKGROUND THREAD** is allowed to modify the UI. Whatever you did, you caused either an exception or a deadlock. You probably tried to use `.Invoke()` from a background thread, while the UI was waiting for the result of the background operation. That's a guaranteed deadlock, and 100% an application bug

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, I need write a scrollviewer control that can friendly in touch and behavior like uwp's ScrollViewer

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thx, but I want you to add issues in github.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update

Now we can find some source code in [Windows UI Library](https://github.com/Microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml) repo.

Answer (score 4):

Unlike .NET, UWP is *not* open-sourced as of now so there is no where to get the uncompiled source code.

You will have to somehow decompile the assemblies if you want to take a look at the code. Decompiling native code is tough though.